# regex get numeration from filename

Tags: regex

Consider the inputs. These are separate strings, not a 5-line string:

```
1. patent1.pdf
2.2.13 menu32.xlsx
2 doctrine.wav
23fruit_12.2_snack.log
2.4. grease_r33mover.plv
```

Expected output:

```
1
2.2.13
2
23
2.4
```

Idea:
Get all chars before first char that is not numeric or a dot. If the resulting string ends with dot(s), then remove trailing dots

Comment: So... have you tried anything at all yet? What didn't work about what you have tried?

Comment: I could get it to work in a C# loop, using algorithm, described in Idea section. But a regex-based solution would be more convenient in my current architecture, alas I'm not that strong in regex

Comment: Have you done any reading at all on how to use regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
^[\d.]*\d
```

- `^` Anchors the match to the beginning of the string
- `[\d.]*` Matches any number of characters that are digits or literal dots
- `\d` Matches one digit character (ensures that the last character is not a dot)

Comment: Very much obliged!